# Excel won't recognize interior color when using sumbycolor funtion

Tags: excel, vba, colors, sum, excel-formula

Hey guys I need help please. I wrote code that conditionally formats cells that contain a specific number then it sorts the colored cells to the bottom and finally I wan't to sum the cells that only contain the interior color. The problem is when I execute the function sumbycolor excel doesn't recognize the cells colors and sums the entire column (color or no color). How do I fix This? Thank you!

```
Function ColorFunction(rColor As Range, rRange As Range, Optional SUM As Boolean)
Dim rCell As Range
Dim lCol As Long
Dim vResult

lCol = rColor.Interior.ColorIndex

If SUM = True Then
    For Each rCell In rRange
        If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = lCol Then
            vResult = WorksheetFunction.SUM(rCell, vResult)
        End If
    Next rCell
Else
    For Each rCell In rRange
        If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = lCol Then
            vResult = 1 + vResult
        End If
    Next rCell
End If

ColorFunction = vResult
End Function

Sub MySheet

'Conditional  formatting
   Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Select
   Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$F1=99999"
   Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
   With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
      .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
      .Color = 65535
      .TintAndShade = 0
   End With
   Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

 'Sort by color column C
   Dim sht As Worksheet
   Dim rngSort As Range
   Dim rngTable As Range
   Set sht = ActiveSheet

   RowCount = sht.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
   Set rngSort = sht.Range("A1:A" & RowCount)
   Set rngTable = Range(Range("A1"), ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell))

    sht.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    sht.Sort.SortFields.Add(rngSort, _
       xlSortOnCellColor, xlDescending, , _
       xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
   With sht.Sort
      .SetRange rngTable
      .Header = xlYes
      .MatchCase = False
      .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
      .SortMethod = xlPinYin
      .Apply
   End With

 'Sum by color
   lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).Row - 1
   sumRange = Range("O2:O" & lr).Address
   lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row - 1
   sumRange2 = Range("P2:P" & lr).Address
   lr = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   CellColor = Range("B" & lr).Address

   Range("C1").Select
   ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Offset(9, 0).Formula = "=(ColorFunction(" & CellColor & "," & sumRange & ",TRUE)+ColorFunction(" & CellColor & "," & sumRange2 & ",TRUE))" 

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't see your SumByColor function.  Conditional Formatting does not change the .interior.color property.  You'll need to check the cells for the conditional format condition, in order to count it.  If your function is not doing that, it won't work as you expect.

Comment: Forgive me for that. I added my color function above.

Comment: It won't work with colors applied by conditional format

Comment: Do I simple change rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = lCol to rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 65535?

Comment: No, as I wrote above, CF does not change the .Interior.ColorIndex property.  You need to check each cell for the conditionally formatting condition, not the color itself

Comment: I could only find some info on this here: http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/CFColors.htm. You might be interested in checking `SumByCFColorIndex` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel's Conditional Format does not change the various color properties of the cell itself (e.g. Interior.Color, Interior.ColorIndex, Font.Color, etc).  In order to work with this, you need to work with the actual Conditional Format formula(s), and test the cell to see which, if any, is applicable.

It's easy to write a short  routine where you have control over the colors and conditions.

For a general purpose routine, you can try EJ Gundersons [MathByColor](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/58499729/Count_Sum_by_Color.xlsm) routines.